# Highcharts data API for line graph using datatime and matching x-axis to y-axis

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I am having a problem populating and matching the x-axis and the y-axis using highcharts.

Am not sure how highcharts handles data, but my thinking is that on the x-axis i populate the dates for the last week and then on the Y-axis have the total amount collect for that day.

My data will have the coordinate for x-axis and y-axis and the name.

**Problem :**
My problem is my data is not consistent. Reason being, for a particular date I might not have any transaction. Hence no transactions for that date.

**Question 1**
Is there a way round this ?

**Question 2**

can I auto generate datetime using highcharts xAxis option and then match these points from my data set ?

> I am not limited to change my data structure, any advise on how to go
> about is highly appreciated.

The data set format was in reference to

https://jsfiddle.net/f2bnc2ox/

Have a look at my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/chapskev/ao1m9s9r/3/

```
   [
       {
          "name":"Open Air Market",
          "data":[
             [
                "2016-06-16",
                450
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-17",
                1980
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-18",
                1650
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-19",
                420
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-20",
                630
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-21",
                660
             ]
          ],
          "keys":[
             "name",
             "y"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Parking Fee",
          "data":[
             [
                "2016-06-17",
                300
             ],
             [
                "2016-06-21",
                1000
             ]
          ],
          "keys":[
             "name",
             "y"
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"Fisheries Daily Revenue",
          "data":[
             [
                "2016-06-21",
                200
             ]
          ],
          "keys":[
             "name",
             "y"
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Comment: In JS arrays are indexed from 0, so [4] is 5th element. Should your required chart look like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/f2bnc2ox/ How your data array looks like in JS?

Comment: @KacperMadej thank you, the jsfiddle helped me out.

Comment: @KacperMadej I have edited my question with my json as per the jsfiddle. Am still unable to populate the line graphs. Kindly help me out

Comment: Welp, I see not recent edits. Last edit is from May 27 at 17:21. Maybe you could also post a JSFiddle demo with hard-coded JSON data returned to JS?

Comment: @KacperMadej I have made the edits kindly assist :)

Comment: You need to set `x` for each data point - https://jsfiddle.net/ao1m9s9r/4/ Highcharts will not match name with category or previous series names, you should set `x`. If you use `datetime` type xAxis and parse your string into dates in times stamp format (milliseconds since 1970.01.01), then you will have `x` as that date for each point. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ornrsyzm/

Comment: @KacperMadej I think the second implementation is workable for me. Thanks a lot this clears up a few issues. Case once I tried to introduce x to the key object, the chart when empty.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? You haven't shared any code so far. Is this really a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear, and I'm not sure this will help anyone else, but I do quite a bit with multidimensional arrays and HighCharts, so I figured I'd take a stab at helping. Making the assumption that your data array is named $aData (for example code).

```
//INIT VARS
$cSeries = '';
$cXAxis = '';
$bAxis = true;

//LOOP TO BUILD SERIES
foreach ($aData AS $nPos => $aSet) {

  //FIRST PASS? BUILD AXIS
  if ($bAxis) {
    $cXAxis .= "xAxis: {\n" .
               "    categories: ['" . implode("','", array_keys($aSet['data'])) . "']\n" .
               "}, ";

    $bAxis = false; //NEED ONLY ONCE
  }

  $cSeries .= ", {\n" .
              "    name: '" . $aSet['name'] . "',\n" .
              "    data: [" . implode(",", $aSet['data']) . "]\n" .
              "}";
}

$cSeries = substr($cSeries, 2); //REMOVE LEADING COMMA
$cOutput = "series: [" . $cSeries . "]\n" . $cXAxis;
```

At the end, $cOutput equals

```
series: [{
  name: 'A revenue',
  data: [7700,5000]
}, {
  name: 'B revenue',
  data: [390,210]
}]
xAxis: {
  categories: ['4','5']
},
```

This matches the two examples of data you are trying to create I believe. You may want to loop through the categories (instead of using implode) so that you can name them something like Apr, May instead.